# Placing text below a figure

Tags: floats, alignment, text

How is it possible to place some text below a floating image?

I use a figure with some variables. I want to define these variables below the figure, so no matter where the image is positioned, they should always be below the figure. They also should be all left aligned. The minimal examle below demonstartes what i want to archieve. I am very thankful for any help!

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{picture.png}
    \caption{Caption caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
With:\newline
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{}
    $l_F$ = Explanation - some words\\
    $l_{Ins}$ = Explanation - some words\\
    $\prescript{}{IMU}{F}_{G}$ = Explanation - some words\\
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Comment: put them before `\end{figure}`

Comment: Both figure and table serve two purposes.  First, they float.  They are formatted into saveboxes and put on a queue for placement (in order), usually at the top of a page.  Second, they enoable \caption (see \@captype).  Also, they are always \columnsidth wide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Caption caption}
\label{fig:label}
\raggedright
With:\par
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
$l_F$ = Explanation - some words\\
$l_{Ins}$ = Explanation - some words\\
$\prescript{}{IMU}{F}_{G}$ = Explanation - some words\\
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to inherit the line spacing from the main text?

Comment: @binex6 You can set `\newlength\baselineskipii` and `\setlength{\baselineskipii}{\baselineskip}` above `figure` float, and set `\setlength{\baselineskip}{\baselineskipii}` in `figure` float.